# Why can't I see the output?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having been learning the basics of javascript. I wrote some code to find the volume of a cylinder. My code validates on W3C BUT I can't see the output. Can you guys guide me on the right direction? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Variables and Arithmatic Example 1</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /*Input: Radius and  height of a cylinder.
         *Processing: Compute volume of cylinder.
         *Output: Volume of cylinder.
        */
        function volume() {
        // Get the radius and height from user.
            var r = parseInt(document.getElementById("radiusInputBox").value);
            var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("heightInputBox").value);

        //Compute volume of cylinder.
            var v = Math.PI * r * r * h;

        //Display volume to user.
        document.getElementByID("volumeDiv").innerHTML = v;
        }               
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cylinder Volume Calculator</h1>
<h2>Please enter value for cylinder radius and height:</h2>
    Radius <input type="text" id="radiusInputBox" size="3"><br>
    Height <input type="text" id="heightInputBox" size="3"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="volume()">Volume</button>
<div id="volumeDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does the browser's debug console show any script errors?

Comment: Just a tip for the future, W3C validates that you have well-formed *HTML*, not javascript. Analyzing the correctness of javascript code is not trivial...

Comment: Did you check your console? First thing to check before posting a question. You should see an error complaining about `getElementByID` is undefined or is not a function. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools Little code review comment: Your function does not take any input, it accesses the DOM for its input, it also does not have output, it modifies the DOM. The lesson is that you should have a function that takes in two values and returns the volume. That function can be tested outside the DOM, then you use that function from your code that touches the DOM

Comment: @juanMendez Thanks for the console tip. I am new to this coding stuff. I forgot I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementByID`

```js
/*Input: Radius and  height of a cylinder.
 *Processing: Compute volume of cylinder.
 *Output: Volume of cylinder.
 */
function volume() {
  // Get the radius and height from user.
  var r = parseInt(document.getElementById("radiusInputBox").value);
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("heightInputBox").value);

  //Compute volume of cylinder.
  var v = Math.PI * r * r * h;

  //Display volume to user.
  document.getElementById("volumeDiv").innerHTML = v;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Cylinder Volume Calculator</h1>
<h2>Please enter value for cylinder radius and height:</h2>
Radius
<input type="text" id="radiusInputBox" size="3">
<br>Height
<input type="text" id="heightInputBox" size="3">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="volume()">Volume</button>
<div id="volumeDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have document.getElementByID, it needs to be document.getElementById.